# JQuery Datatable is not working as responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to use jQuery datatable in my project and need to create it as responsive. I don't want the inbuilt paging, sorting, searching of the datatable. Instead I need to use lazy loading in that while user scrolls to the end. `This is the model fiddle of my progress,`https://jsfiddle.net/Noblemo/y9ye3yvj/.
I'm using table.row.add method to add rows in to the datatable. My issue is, while adding data, the table shows horizontal scroll bar. I need only vertical scroll bar. Horizontal over flow of data should be responsive. Please help me.

Comment: Your jsfiddle throws a `table is undefined` error

Comment: @markpsmith, I got that error. But I have defined a variable `table`. I'm not getting this error in my project. I done the same in the fiddle. I don't have more experience in jsfiddle.

Comment: @markpsmith, please check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Noblemo/y9ye3yvj/4/ I have fixed that error. But still the table is not responsive.